# Why does this program always give the same output?

Tags: c++

When i run this code it always gives "Total Number is 1959530850". I cannot understand why  that is? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b,total;
    cout << "Enter First Number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter Second Number \n";
    cin >> b;
    total = a + b;
    cout << "Total Number is "<< total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you by chance always entering numbers that add up to that particular sum?

Comment: http://ideone.com/gFbrzo

Comment: Is a *stale* version of the build - perhaps with a particular magic number - being run?

Comment: Time for "Rebuild All"

Comment: I run it on codeblock and i tried it many times. but all the time i got the same result. i can not understand what is wrong

Comment: @RRD, Did you try a ctrl-F11?

Comment: What do you input? Try inputting 2 and 4. Does it still give you total 1959530850?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what output you get when you add `cout << a << endl;` and `cout << b << endl;` right after you've read these variables' values via `cin >>`.

Comment: What compiler are you using with Code::Blocks?

Comment: The code you've given clearly works as expected, see @Derek's link. You'll have to provide more specific information or there's no way it can be solved.